# use foreach loop dynamically in php

Tags: php, loops, foreach

i want use **foreach** loop dynamically in php, i have task to print AAA to **999** and i'm using this code and it's work perfect,

**[Reference :: http://www.onlinecode.org/generate-string-aaaa-9999-using-php-code/](http://www.onlinecode.org/generate-string-aaaa-9999-using-php-code/)**

```
$addalphabeth = array_merge(range('A', 'Z'), range(0,9));
$setcharacter = [];
foreach ($addalphabeth as $setcharacter[0]) {
  foreach ($addalphabeth as $setcharacter[1]) {
    foreach ($addalphabeth as $setcharacter[2]) {
        //$setcatalog[] = vsprintf('%s%s%s', $setcharacter);
        echo "<b>".vsprintf('%s%s%s', $setcharacter)."</b>";
        echo "<br>";
    }
  }
}
```

now my issue is have to print that **AAAAA** to **99999** (need loop 5 time) or **AAAAAAAA** to **99999999** (need loop 8 time) ,
so for this i use loop **n time**. I have no idea how to do it, **any help or suggestion will be appreciated**.

Comment: Any reason for the Downvote please?

Comment: From your code, it looks like you could combine a `foreach` and `for` loop with `n` iterations.

Comment: @fubar : thanks for suggestion

Comment: Recusion might work well too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evening, here is my solution, using recursion.
To setup a recursion, you have to think of two things.  What is your stop condition, and what do to with non-stopping conditions.

- Stopping condition:  when you ask for only 1 char width, simply loop through each member of $addalphabeth.  And since that width == 1 scenario will happen when the final width you want is >1, add the prefix to it.
- Non-stopping condition: lets start with width 2.  You want the every first char to be followed by all possible second chars.  So call the function with width = 1 and prefix = the first char.
- for 3, you want the first char followed by every char in the second position, followed by every char in the third position.
- and so on...
- So the general case is: from left to right, with n chars width, loop on every char, and print every possible combination of n-1 chars after it.

So here is the code:

```
function printAto9($width,$prefix = '')
{
    $chars = array_merge(range('A', 'Z'), range(0,9));
    if ($width == 1)
    {
        foreach ($chars as $char)
        {
            echo "$prefix$char\n";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $width--;
        foreach ($chars as $char)
        {
            echo printAto9($width,$prefix . $char);
        }
    }
}

printAto9(5);
```

I put `printAto9(5);` as a test, you can use whatever.
But careful, the output is monstrous pretty quick, and you can kill your php (memory or time limit).

Comment: i have find solution, but really good code thanks for answer.

Comment: @JON Can u post your solution as an another answer ?